# Setting up group permissions in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, permissions

I've a problem with Django Rest Framework.

I wish to set a group-specific permissions with the following code, which I set in admin.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission

# Creating staff group and handling group permissions
staff_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Staff')

def staff_has_crud_permissions(obj):
    add_obj = Permission.objects.get(codename=f'add_{obj}')
    change_obj = Permission.objects.get(codename=f'change_{obj}')
    delete_obj = Permission.objects.get(codename=f'delete_{obj}')
    view_obj = Permission.objects.get(codename=f'view_{obj}')

    staff_group.permissions.add(add_obj)
    staff_group.permissions.add(change_obj)
    staff_group.permissions.add(delete_obj)
    staff_group.permissions.add(view_obj)
    print(staff_group.permissions)


staff_has_crud_permissions('bar')
```

Yet, when the line `print(staff_group.permissions`runs, I get `auth.Permission.None`. Why doesn't it succeed?

Answer (score 0):

to check the permissions, use

```
staff_group.permissions.all()
```

this will return the queryset containing all the permissions of staff_group.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work...